# measure power consumption of microcontroller (low power mode) in order to optimize my code

Tags: performance-testing, microcontroller

I'm developing code for a microcontroller (specifically MSP432P401R LaunchPad).

I'd like to measure the power consumption of the microcontroller while running my code, in order to optimize it, expecially in low power mode.
The dev board is connected through USB to my computer.

Is it possible? Do I need some special instruments? I have an oscilloscope. I've read about current probes for oscilloscopes, but they seems very expensive.
Is there any other way?

The mcu I bought has 80 µA/MHz current consumption in low power mode. Is there a way to measure such low level of current?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSP432P401R LaunchPad has built in EnergyTrace capabilities. These can be accessed via TI's Code Composer Studio IDE. Check the user guide for the launchpad board (SLAU597B) for details of how to enable this. You can get rather detailed information about energy use including relating usage back to code. I haven't explored these features deeply, but it has the distinct advantage of not needing any additional equipment.

Otherwise, yes you can measure such low current consumption with conventional instruments, but it must be done "very delicately". As a software guy, it's beyond my abilities and when I have done it, it was always with a good EE at my side on a custom board that was specifically designed to be able to measure such things and electrically isolate different parts of the system.

Also, one minor point. The 80 uA/MHz current consumption is for active mode processing. In low power sleep modes, standby current consumption can drop to just a few microAmps and in the very lowest power modes even to the nanoAmp range. The data sheet is a wealth of confusing information about this.

Comment: Thank you for your question. It is very helpful. I was able to find more information about the EnergyTrace.